# SAGA raster calculator, ifelse command syntax problem

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator, saga

I would like to combine two raster in Raster calculator of Saga.

With raster calculator of QGIS , I have no problem, but with ifelse command syntax of Saga, the operation don't run. The operation is :

```
(( "A" < 25) AND ( ( "B">0.05 ) AND ( "B"<0.1)))*1 + (( "A" >= 25) AND ( ( "B">0.05 ) AND ( "B"<0.1)))*2 + (( "A" < 15) AND ( ( "B" >= 0.1 ) AND ( "B"<0.3)))*1+ ((( "A" >= 15) AND ("A"<35)) AND ( ( "B" >= 0.1 ) AND ( "B"<0.3)))*2+ (( "A" >= 35) AND ( ( "B" >= 0.1 ) AND ( "B"<0.3)))*3+ (( "A" < 25) AND ( ( "B" >= 0.3 ) AND ( "B"<0.5)))*2+ (( "A" >= 25) AND ( ( "B" >= 0.3 ) AND ( "B"<0.5)))*3+ (( "A" <15) AND ( ( "B" >= 0.5 ) AND ( "B"<0.8)))*2+ ((( "A" >= 15) AND ("A"<35)) AND ( ( "B" >= 0.5 ) AND ( "B"<0.8)))*3+ (( "A" >= 35) AND ( ( "B" >= 0.5 ) AND ( "B"<0.8)))*4+ (( "A" <5) AND ( "B" >= 0.8 )) *2+ ((( "A" >= 5) AND ("A"<25)) AND ( "B" >= 0.8))*3+ (( "A" >= 25) AND ( "B" >= 0.8 )) *4
```

where A e B are rasters (DEM and SLOPE)

Answer (score 3):

The `ifelse` operator is not necessary in your expression. For instance, consider its first addendum:

```
(( "A" < 25) AND ( ( "B">0.05 ) AND ( "B"<0.1)))*1
```

Using the SAGA Grid calculator syntax, it could be something like:

```
lt(a,25)*gt(b,0.05)*lt(b,0.1)*1
```

Instead, considering the second addendum:

```
+ (( "A" >= 25) AND ( ( "B">0.05 ) AND ( "B"<0.1)))*2
```

it could be rewritten as:

```
+(1-lt(a,25))*gt(b,0.05)*lt(b,0.1)*2
```

...and so on.

Comment: OK thanks. And the expression : ((( "A"   >=  15) and ("A"<35)) and   (  ( "B" >= 0.1 )  and  ( "B"<0.3)))*2  ???

Comment: Don't mention it. It should be `(1-lt(a,15))*lt(a,35)*(1-lt(b,0.1))*lt(b,0.3)*2`.